# Is there a solution for the [random] tag chaos?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are the following tags on SO:

- random
- random-number-generator
- pseudo-random-numbers
- random-generator
- random-numbers
- <s>random-number</s> (retagged to [random-numbers](/questions/tagged/random-numbers))

All of them means basically the same. Additionally, there is also:

- rand
- random-alpha-generator
- random-string
- random-string-generator

My questions:

- Could possibly somebody clean it up?
- Is it possible to send a message to the creator of a tag to make them aware of the (nearly) duplicate?
- Can the creator of a tag merge in into another one?

Comment: Chaos?  How do you pass up the title "Is there a solution for the tag *randomness*?"  ;)

Comment: Nice idea:D Regarding "random-number (retagged to random-numbers)" I see it happened, but the tag "random-number" still exists (0 times used).

Comment: When a tag is reduced to 0 count, it'll stay in the system until a daily script runs at the end of the day to prune it. Just make sure it stays at 0 until then.

Answer (score 8):

I cleaned a bunch of these up and folded them into `random`.  I also created tag synonyms for the tags I merged.  Here's what I left in place.

[image: rand tags]

`srand` and `boost-rand` are specific enough that I think they can have their own tags.  `random-access` is a separate topic too, so I left that alone.

The only one that I merged that I felt was questionable was `rand`.  I know that's a function in a lot of languages, but it's universally a PRNG so I think the tag meaning is clear.  (If I'm wrong about this, somebody let me know.)

Comment: Bill, can you put synonyms in place for those tags that you merged into **`[random]`**?

Comment: @Justin: Sure can.

Comment: thanks.  That should keep those tags at `0` from now on then.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem in this special case. The existence of the tag "retag-request" (revealed to by somebody having put on my question) answers my questions. Those retag-requests are surely no perfect solution, but I'm not sure if there could be a better one.

Comment: @maaartinus: Retag requests are one part of the solution, but as @Justin pointed out [tag synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) are the other.  For example, any time anyone tries to add the tag `random-numbers` in the future it will automatically get converted to `random`.